# my code cant display the picture from db?

Tags: php

Please help cant display image when I use php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM obs") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<center><table><tr><th width=200>Obs Number</th><th width=200>Name</th><th width=200>Purpose</th><th width=200>Date Of OB</th><th width=200>Destination</th><th width=200>Image</th></tr></center>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';

    //cant display image

    echo '<tr> <input type="hidden" name="showimage[]" value="'. $row['OBS_NUMBER'].'" >';
    echo '<td width=200>' . $row['OBS_NUMBER'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td width=200>' . $row['NAME'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td width=200>' . $row['PURPOSE'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td width=200>' . $row['DATE_OF_OB'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td width=200>' . $row['DESTINATION'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td width=200> <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['imagesobs']) . '" width="250"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: function displayimage()
            {
                $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                mysql_select_db("corporate_personnel_order_for_2016",$con);
                $qry="select * from obs where OBS_NUMBER='showimage' ";
                $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[2].' "> ';
                }
                mysql_close($con);   
            }

Comment: the picture will display if i use the mysql insert but when i insert using php it cant display the image

Comment: need you to show how you encode the image.. on your img src shouldn't it be base64_decode?

Comment: echo '<td width=200> <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['imagesobs']) . '" width="250"></td>';

Comment: i meant encode.. base64_encode is done so you can save the data on db.. so when you want to display it you can just use base64_decode. try changing it to decode.. maybe that's just the problem here.

Comment: what line? cant understand show me the code

Comment: echo '<td width=200> <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_decode($row['imagesobs']) . '" width="250"></td>'

Comment: it shows the code of the picture not the image

Comment: assuming that you have saved the encoded image correctly.. then i think the issue is with the image format... on src you are using jpeg format... so maybe the encoded string is not a jpeg?

Comment: it's the same even if I save an jpeg picture it still shows the code not the image

Comment: well tried it echo '<td width=200> <img src="data:image/png;base64,XXXXXX"></td> '; i can see the actual image.
use this to test an image https://www.base64-image.de/... if it's working using a test image from this site then there must be something wrong with your saved image... one last thing try this <td width=200> <img src="'. base64_decode($row['imagesobs']) . '" width="250"></td>';

Comment: now it show no image

Comment: do you have a test domain so i can view it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff help

Comment: jonas.. well if you don't have a test server.. can you just view source and copy the first few parts of the <img src="....."

Comment: this one?   '<td width=200> <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['imagesobs']) . '" width="250"></td>';

Comment: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,aVZCT1J3MEtHZ29BQUFBTlNVaEVVZ0FBQXpZQUFBSXVDQUlBQUFEaTN3cFVBQUFBQVhOU1IwSUFyczRjNlFBQUFBUm5RVTFCQUFDeGp3djhZUVVBQUFBSmNFaFpjd0FBRHNNQUFBN0RBY2R2cUdRQUFFY1ZTVVJCVkhoZTdaekJtZXMy

Comment: sorry for the late reply.